# How can I use standard latex font (computer modern) in a web page?

Tags: html, fonts

Is there an easy way to display webpages in computer modern font?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most stable way to do this I found was to base64 a font I found at http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/. I used the cmunrm.otf from there, base64'ed it and put it as a font face in my css.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "my-font";
  src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,T1R...gP5w/kP+RAA format("opentype");
}

body {
  font-family: "my-font";
}
```

You can see an example at https://jsfiddle.net/jtvx9auo/

While you could also simply download the otf file and put it to your server, I found base64ing to be more reliable, e.g. when trying to convert to pdf using wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still stumbles upon this (2020+) looking for the optimised web fonts rather than the larger `.otf` fonts which are used in the answer above, I've hosted the Computer Modern font family via the jsDelivr CDN.

To use it, you can add a `<link>` to your html `<head>` which requests the optimised fonts through the following address:

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aaaakshat/cm-web-fonts@latest/fonts.css`

And then just add the `Computer Modern Serif` or sans-serif families directly in your css files.

**Example Code:**

```html
<head>
  <!-- Other imports... -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aaaakshat/cm-web-fonts@latest/fonts.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Computer Modern Serif", serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Check out the [full documentation here](https://github.com/aaaakshat/cm-web-fonts)